# Definite integral involving arcTan and $e^x$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate $$\int_{-\pi/6}^{\pi/6}\frac{\tan^{-1}x}{\mathrm{e}^x+1} \,\mathrm{d} x $$

My try: I used integration by parts using $\tan^{-1}x$ as the first function and $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^x+1}$ as second function but again i faced with a difficult integral with Integrand:

$$\frac{\log_{e}(e^x+1)}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: Are you sure it should not be $\arctan x^2$, $\arctan |x|$ or anything along those lines? If $f(x) = f(-x)$ then
$$
\int_{-a}^a \frac{f(x)}{e^x+1}\,\mathrm{d}x
= \int_{0}^a f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x
$$
Because
$$
\int_{-a}^a f(x)\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^a f(x) + f(-x) \mathrm{d}x
$$

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar, Yes i am sure its not what you expected...

Comment: Where did this integral come from? Do you have a good reason to expect it to have a closed form in terms of well-known functions and constants?

Comment: The output doesn't seem to be too rational...this integral seems to be coming out of nowhere, and just random stuff...wolframalpha says, the integral is $0.0224439...$

Comment: What is its answer sir,i am curious to know?@EkaveeraKumarSharma

Answer (score 1):

For now, we may use series; since

$$\frac{1}{1+e^x} = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n}{e^{nx}}},$$ valid for $|e^x|<1$, and

$$\tan^{-1}x = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n}}}{{2n + 1}}{x^{2n + 1}}}, $$  valid for $|x| <1$, then the series

$$\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{k + n}}}}{{2k + 1}}{x^{2k + 1}}} } {e^{nx}}$$, valid for $|xe^x|<r<1$

and converges uniformly there. So that 
\begin{align}
\int {\frac{{ta{n^{ - 1}}x}}{{1 + {e^x}}}dx}  &= \int {\left( {\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{k + n}}}}{{2k + 1}}{x^{2k + 1}}} } {e^{nx}}} \right)dx} 
\\
&= \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{k + n}}}}{{2k + 1}}} } \left( {\int {{x^{2k + 1}}{e^{nx}}dx} } \right)
\end{align}
and of course the integral ${\int {{x^{2k + 1}}{e^{nx}}dx} }$ follows by parts.